# How to read a XML file and removing some set of Tags

Tags: java

I have a XML file having number of store elements(see example below) and in store it have its date and time of availability in exception elements.
from this XML file I need to remove all the exception elements from a particular day/date(e.g. I need to delete all the exception elements after 16th Dec).
I need to write a java program to delete these exception elements from a particular date and generate a new file. Can some one please help me in finding the solution.

```
<stores>
<store>
<number>101</number>
<exception_hours>
<exception>
<date>
<![S[2013-12-16]]>
</date>
<hours>
<![S[09:00 to 22:00]]>
</hours>
</exception>
<exception>
<date>
<![S[2013-12-18]]>
</date>
<hours>
<![S[08:00 to 23:00]]>
</hours>
</exception>
<exception>
<date>
<![S[2013-12-20]]>
</date>
<hours>
<![S[08:00 to 23:00]]>
</hours>
</exception>
<exception>
<date>
<![S[2013-12-19]]>
</date>
<hours>
<![S[09:00 to 22:00]]>
</hours>
</exception>
<exception>
<date>
<![S[2013-12-15]]>
</date>
<hours>
<![S[10:00 to 19:00]]>
</hours>
</exception>
<exception>
<date>
<![S[2013-12-14]]>
</date>
<hours>
<![S[09:00 to 19:00]]>
</hours>
</exception>
</exception_hours>
</store>
<store>
.
.
.

</store>
</stores>
```

Comment: xml filter can be nicely done using [XSLT][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604497/xslt-processing-with-java

Comment: Any update on this? how did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to use `JAXB` (see [Use JAXB to create Object from XML String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458833/use-jaxb-to-create-object-from-xml-string) for one of many examples). Then you may do whatever you need with this, just operating on Java objects.

Hope it helps and you don't ask us to write this code for you :-)