# convert json source to java object

Tags: java, json

I have an url (`https://`) which includes `json` data but it has a protection against called `JSON highjacking exploit` I think because the source begins with:
`)]}',`
and the source is like:

```
  [
  {
    "address": {
        "street": "Neuenfelder Str",
        "housenumber": "13A",
        "postalcode": "21109",
        "city": "Hamburg",
        "geoLocation": {
            "lat": "52.092309",
            "lng": "5.130041"
        }
    },
    "distance": 0
  },
  {
    "address": {
        "street": "Umber Str",
        "housenumber": "2",
        "postalcode": "22567",
        "city": "Berlin",
        "geoLocation": {
            "lat": "51.5761166",
            "lng": "5.0377286"
        }
    },
    "distance": 0
  },
  .....]
```

I tried to create client code and consume this json by using `Jackson`, `gson` and even `org.json` but I got parsing error :

> Could not read document: Unexpected character (')' (code 41)):
>   expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false'
>   or 'null')

I could convert `json` to `Java` object by saving as a file and remove these characters `)]}'`.

But I need to know is there any way to convert this source as a normal way we do without saving as a document and just use these libraries(`ObjectMapper` or `ResponseEntity`).

Comment: How does the source begin with `)]}',`?

Comment: take this source in String and trim starting characters `)]}'`

Comment: Yeah my question is that is there any way to convert java object without any trim operation as well

Comment: Sounds like the question is not how to convert json to java, but how to fix a broken piece of json.

Comment: Why do you want an approach without removing the invalid characters? That is like asking, what is "1 + 1?" but not taking 2 as an answer.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056382/xml-to-json-conversion-in-java-with-xml-attributes/41056755#41056755 answer. It is for xml but useful for you.

Comment: You have to strip the first characters but as you didn't include any source code about reading the JSON and what from we cannot help you.

Comment: If you have control over the server code which is sending out the json then make sure that it sends valid json otherwise you will have to trim it to make it valid.

Comment: @RobCo It is not to fix a broken piece of json. The source is protected against JSON highjacking exploit which means not broken for me or should I think it is broken? Maybe there is a library to parse protected JSON source and I don't know that's why I asked

Comment: @Wietlol Should I approach with removing the invalid characters? My first approach is trim invalid ones. But I am curios developer and I want to know and be sure is there any way or any library to  achieve it?

Comment: @kit the way you meantioned seems work but I am gonna try it and share the results. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All major JSON libraries you mentioned do NOT provide any way of parsing JSON documents you are talking about: they can just work with *well-formed* JSON documents, nothing else, and that's the only and justified their responsibility. You mentioned a document that is not a valid JSON, so that's the only reason of why all of them fail to parse it. However, all of the libraries you mentioned in your question work with `Reader`s transparently, and having just removed those five characters, you can *fix* the broken JSON document (and it's broken for the JSON standard or any JSON tool) so it could be consumed by any of those library. Please note that you don't need a "special" library of any kind (ok, let's assume such a library exists, but what if it lacks any features that you can use with your favorite JSON library, so that making you sad?), because you can just make it work for any. Performance note: you don't need to use strings in order to save memory and being able to process huge JSON documents as well.

Consider the following "JSON" document:

```
)]}',{"foo":"bar"}
```

Knowing that the very first five characters prevent any JSON parser to parse it, you can easily just strip them:

```java
private static final char[] protectingCharacters = {
        ')', ']', '}', '\'', ','
};

static Reader stripProtection(final Reader reader)
        throws IOException {
    // Allocating a temporary buffer
    final char[] buffer = new char[protectingCharacters.length];
    // Check if the given Reader instance supports reading ahead, and wrap if necessary
    // This is necessary in order to restore the reader position
    final Reader normalizedReader = reader.markSupported() ? reader : new BufferedReader(reader);
    // Memorizing the current position telling the reader to limit its internal buffer size just with five characters
    normalizedReader.mark(protectingCharacters.length);
    // Reading five characters to the buffer
    // We don't need to check how many characters were read -- we'll check it below
    normalizedReader.read(buffer, 0, protectingCharacters.length);
    // Not a protecting mark?
    if ( !Arrays.equals(protectingCharacters, buffer) ) {
        // Then just rewind the reader pointer to the position stored with the mark() invocation
        normalizedReader.reset();
    }
    // Or assume that skipping five characters is fine
    return normalizedReader;
}
```

The following examples use the `stripProtection` method for the Gson, Jackson and org.json libraries parsing the given input stream to create their respective JSON tree models for simplicity:

```java
static void testWithGson()
        throws IOException {
    try ( final Reader reader = stripProtection(getPackageResourceReader(Q42971905.class, "no-hijacking.json")) ) {
        final JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        final JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(reader);
        System.out.println(jsonElement);
    }
}

static void testWithJackson()
        throws IOException {
    try ( final Reader reader = stripProtection(getPackageResourceReader(Q42971905.class, "no-hijacking.json")) ) {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(reader);
        System.out.println(jsonNode);
    }
}

static void testWithOrgJson()
        throws IOException {
    try ( final Reader reader = stripProtection(getPackageResourceReader(Q42971905.class, "no-hijacking.json")) ) {
        final JSONTokener jsonTokener = new JSONTokener(reader);
        final Object value = jsonTokener.nextValue();
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

All three methods produce the following output:

> {"foo":"bar"}

If, for some reason, you need to generate such documents, you just have to write a method like this:

```java
static Writer coverWithProtection(final Writer writer)
        throws IOException {
    writer.write(protectingCharacters);
    return writer;
}
```

And pass the writer to the corresponding JSON library you're using. This method will just prepend the writer output with `)]}',`.

Comment: Thank you so much,I needed to be sure. It's so explanatory. I tried your solution, `jsonNode` returns well formed json documents and it's more reasonable as the performance is a concern.