# Getting JSON objects / arrays using GSON library without converting to pojos

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I used jackson to convert json strings to json objects / arrays like so:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(myXmlString);
JSONObject userObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("user"); // is there a GSON version of this? 
JSONArray orders = userObj.getJSONArray("orders");
```

My main question is: is there a GSON version of getting json objects / arrays without converting to a pojo? My json is very complex so it's difficult to create pojos.

Secondly, does gson allow you to convert an xml string to json like jackson does (line 1)?

Comment: Instead of using POJOs you might want to try deserializing json into HashMap<String, Object>. I do this in my projects and everything works fine. To get to the values of HashMap you need to know they predefined keys tho

Answer (score 0):

For the first question:

You can create a `JsonObject` from a **json string**

```
String json = "{ \"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": false}";
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
```

otherwise you can create a `Map` object

```
String jsonString = "{'employee.name':'Bob','employee.salary':10000}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map map = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Map.class);
```

for reference: https://www.baeldung.com/gson-json-to-map

For the second question:

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648774/convert-an-xml-file-to-json-using-using-gson) question in stackoverflow

Comment: Did you read what he need, before writing the code , you should read the question well

Comment: what do you mean? My answer is exactly what he needs (?), he has json string that must be converted with GSON, without using a POJO. My code does exactly that. 

Did I miss something obvious?

Comment: For the second one, I can't use jaxb unfortunately. Don't think GSON can do this alone?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a GSON version of getting json objects / arrays without
>   converting to a pojo?

Something like this can do the job

```
import com.google.gson.*;

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

JsonElement json = parser.parse(myJsonString);

//get as object
JsonObject obj = json.getAsJsonObject();

//get as array
JsonArray arr = json.getAsJsonArray();
```

> does gson allow you to convert an xml string to json like jackson does

No